# Hyperlinks broken on Excel 2010

Tags: windows, ms-office

I have a Intranet that index a lot of excel and word documents. many of them has a lot of Hyperlinks to other files in this way: http://my-site/path/document.xls

The problem is on Windows 10 + Office 2010.

I'm able to open a main doc, then I click on an child hyperlink and it works perfectly. The issue appear when I save the child document, so in the parent doc (which has the link), the link never works again. Instead of that, a webpage is opened sayin "XML Page cannot be displayed a non valid character were found"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found that is a change since Office 2010 in where HyperLinks are build using and absolute path instead of relative.!

In there http://file is replaced by file:///\path to the file in the server.